# In JMETER CMD console window-Issue on while Adding Components under Threadgroup using mouse scrolling except Listeners

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, performance-testing

While Adding Components under Threadgroup using mouse scroll it will simply
hangs and in jmeter CMD windows displaying exception like :

```
Uncaught Exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1. See log file
for details.
Uncaught Exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1. See log file
for details.
Uncaught Exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -16. See log file
for details.
Uncaught Exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -16. See log  file
for details.
Uncaught Exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -19. See log file
for details.
Uncaught Exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -19. See log file
for details.
```

Why Jmeter CMD showing me this

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I have seen this in Jmeter when you use `View Results Tree` listener & switch to different response types to XML/JSON/TXT etc with the test results.

There was also a bug that Java v8 does not work with JMeter. http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jmeter-issues/201401.mbox/%3Cbug-56080-58895@https.issues.apache.org/bugzilla/%3E

See if Java 6 or 7 resolves the issue.